# Ftrace overhead comparison : trace_printk v/s custom tracepoint in linux

Tags: linux, performance, profiling, perf, ftrace

What's the overhead comparison of `trace_printk` message and adding a custom `Ftrace tracepoint` in the Linux kernel?

Since both `trace_printk` and custom `tracepoint` logs in trace log file, I'm guessing there overheads would be same while performance measurements?

I want to print time taken by certain Linux kernel functions (using ktime_get() and their difference), and log them using the trace_printk call.